# Identification of Theatrical Play about Vietnam War

Tags: identification-request, theater

(I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask about works of theater, so let me know if this question is better posed elsewhere.)

I'm interested in identifying a play about a man's experience as a soldier in Vietnam in 1971.  The man has a friend named Chick, who is a writer.  Over the course of the drama, the man begins to suspect Chick is secretly in league with the Viet Cong, and decides he's a traitor, but is conflicted about this.  Chick introduces the man to Buddhism.  It might involve the man writing letters or journal entries to his mom over the course of his deployment.  Chick also gives the man drugs, including marijuana and mescaline, I think.  The man seems to have a lot of cognitive dissonance between wanting to fight and trying to reconcile the reality of killing people.  He realizes he can only fight for himself, and taking sides will never work.

Apologies for the lack of coherent details, but hopefully this is enough.  Let me know if there's any other information I can try to provide.

Comment: This is perfectly on-topic here, don't worry: both theatre and ID questions are fine for this site. You might want to have a look at the [ID tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) though, especially the checklist which might help to jog your memory for more details that could make this more findable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Kennedy's Children" by Robert Patrick came up in Google Books searches for *Vietnam "friend chick" Mark*. It can be read on [pointlessplea.wordpress.com](https://pointlessplea.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/notes-on-producing-kennedys-children/).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy%27s_Children) the soldier character, Mark, was written originally by Patrick for his Off-Broadway play in 1970 "A Bad Place to Get Your Head".